# Russian subtitles don't work in vlc

Tags: lubuntu, vlc, subtitle

I have an .mkv file with built-in russian subtitles which I try to run on vlc version 2.2.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but there appears to be garbage instead of subtitles. I've tried to change subtitles' encoding in vlc settings multiple times, I've also tried to remove vlc, purge vlc, and reinstall it via apt-get and ubuntu software center. I have no problem with russian font on my OS since I can see and type russian letters in other programs. Any ideas?